# Centos 6.6, python 2.7.2 object has no attribute 'StringIO

Tags: python-2.7, docker, centos6

I'm trying to run my python tests inside docker container. Here is a part of Dockerfile that installs python .2.7.2 using CentsOS 6.6:

```
RUN cd /tmp && \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tgz && \
    tar xvfz Python-2.7.2.tgz && \
    cd Python-2.7.2 && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && \
    make && \
    make altinstall

RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python

RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | /usr/local/bin/python2.7
RUN /usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 pip
RUN pip install python-gflags sqlparse pyyaml requests HTTPretty
```

I get an exception while running my tests inside docker container:

```
import io
# some code here...
buf = io.StringIO(data)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StringIO'
```

I don't get this exception while running tests locally or on server env.

I tried to execute simple script in docker container:

```
import io
print io.StringIO(None)
```

Works fine. I'm confused. What could be the problem here?

@Blckknght, you are right, code has module named **io**:

`io.__file__ :::  /root/containerfolder/proejct/py/src/common/io.pyc`. But I can reproduce it only in **docker**. When I copy-paste code to **server** or run it **locally**, I'm getting right

`io.__file__ :::  /opt/py/ext/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/io.pyc`

What is the right way to fix it exept renaming the module :) ?

**ANSWER:**

- @Blckknght is right, there is a code module named "IO"
  (!!!uppercase!!!) that hides built-in "io"
- My "local" MacOS FS is case insensitive, but case preserving, it distinguishes io and IO, that is why I'm getting correct "io" locally.
- Server has case-sensitive FS
- Docker image has case insensitive FS. That is why it fails only there.

It was nice challenge, thanks :)

Comment: I'd guess that you have a local module named `io.py` on your dev system that's not on the server. It's shadowing the builtin `io` module, so you're not finding the things you expect in that module.

Comment: I think that @Blckknght is right. You can view the path of the imported module by doing a print io.__file__ to be sure that the proper one is imported.

Comment: Hm... will try, I see io.StringIO problem only in docker. Server/dev laptop don't have such problems.

Comment: Please see updated question, you were right...

Comment: Instead of renaming the module, you could put it inside another package such that its always qualified as `foo.io` instead of `io`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- @Blckknght is right, there is a code module named "IO" (!!!uppercase!!!) that hides built-in "io"
- My "local" MacOS FS is case insensitive, but case preserving, it distinguishes io and IO, that is why I'm getting correct "io" locally.
- Server has case-sensitive FS
- Docker image has case insensitive FS. That is why it fails only there.

It was nice challenge, thanks :)